# Objects do not fit inside the mobile screen :three.js

Tags: three.js

My scene perfectly works on desktop screen according to my expected object size and tween. However when i view it on my mobile browser(chrome-uptodate) the scene seems to be uneven.

- I have used resize function
- problem is when the mobile is on portrait position
- Any other way to make my scene fit on mobile screen ?

here is the script which i used
https://jsfiddle.net/r49xdzs9/

```
window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
        function onWindowResize() {
                camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
                webGLRenderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            }
```

[image: scene when viewed on mobile chrome browser]
[image: Scene when viewed on desktop]

Comment: Take a look at [this topic](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-resizing-the-canvas.html) about resizing.

Comment: @mlkn can you please tell me if there is any working example based on this link ?